# Compare CSV Values Against Another CSV And Output Results

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv containing various columns (full_log.csv).  One of the columns is labeled "HASH" and contains the hash value of the file shown in that row. For Example, my columns would have the following headers:

### Filename - Hash - Hostname - Date

I need my python script to take another CSV (hashes.csv) containing only 1 column of multiple hash values, and compare the hash values against my the HASH column in my full_log.csv.

Anytime it finds a match I want it to output the entire row that contains the hash to an additional CSV (output.csv).  So my output.csv will contain only the rows of full_log.csv that contain any of the hash values found in hashes.csv, if that makes sense.

So far I have the following.  It works for the hash value that I manually enter in the script, but now I need it to look at hashes.csv to compare instead of manually putting the hash in the script, and instead of printing the results I need to export them to output.csv.

```
import csv

with open('full_log.csv', 'rb') as input_file1:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file1)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row ['HASH'] == 'FB7D9605D1A38E38AA4C14C6F3622E5C3C832683']

for row in rows:
    print row
```

Comment: Read all the hashes into a list, then use `List.index()` function to determine if any given hash is in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generate a `set` from the `hashes.csv` file. Using membership in that set as a filter, I would iterate over the `full_log.csv` file, outputting only those lines that match.

```
import csv

with open('hashes.csv') as hashes:
    hashes = csv.reader(hashes)
    hashes = set(row[0] for row in hashes)

with open('full_log.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(row for row in reader if row['Hash'] in hashes)
```

Answer (score 1):

look at pandas lib for python:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

it has various helpful function for your question, easily read, transform and write to csv file

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the rows of files and hashes and using a filter with `any` to return matches in the collection of hashes:

```
matching_rows = []
with open('full_log.csv', 'rb') as file1, open('hashes.csv', 'rb') as file2:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file1)
    hash_reader = csv.DictReader(file2)
    matching_rows = [row for row in reader if any(row['Hash'] == r['Hash'] for r in hash_reader)]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f)
    writer.writerows(matching_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unclear as to exactly how much help that you require in solving this. I will assume that you do not need a full solution, but rather, simply tips on how to craft your solution.

First question, which file is larger? If you know that hashes.csv is not too large, meaning it will fit in memory with no problem, then I would simply suck that file in one line at a time and store each hash entry in a Set variable. I won't provide full code, but the general structure is as follows:

```
hashes = Set()
for each line in the hashes.csv file
    hashes.add(hash from the line)
```

Now, I believe you to already know how to read a CSV file, since you have an example above, but, what you want to do is to now iterate through each row in the full log CSV file. For each of those lines, do not check to see if the hash is a specific value, instead, check to see if that value is contained in the hashes variable. if it is, then use the CSV writer to write the single line to a file.

The biggest gotcha, I think, is knowing if the hashes will always be in a particular case so that you can perform the compare. For example, if one file uses uppercase for the HASH and the other uses lowercase, then you need to be sure to convert to use the same case.